# Linq Syntax Any()

Tags: c#, linq, any

I have this pseudo object

```
list<ListOfCars>{
   list<ListOfParts>
}
```

I currently have this query

```
ListOfCars.Where(x => x.ListofParts.Any(y => y.PartIsDeleted == false));
```

On my investigation, it returns something if atleast 1 item satisfies the condition in the `Any(y => y.PartIsDeleted == false)`.

My question is what is the syntax for something like this

```
SELECT * FROM ListOfCars cars WHERE  cars.ListOfParts.PartIsDeleted = false
```

Comment: `ListOfParts` is a list. You have to anyway use an aggregate function like `Any` or `All`

Comment: yes, that's why I used Any(), but it seems that it returns nothing if no item satisfies the condition inside the Any()

Comment: `Any` means at least one satisfying the condition.

Comment: Can you post real C# code instead of pseudo code? It's hard to understand what your pseudocode actually means.

Comment: I think the problem is not where you post show more detail

Comment: Hi guys Tommy's 3rd code worked. thanks for you efforts! I'm just now trying to understand the difference of Any(y => y.PartIsDeleted == false) and Any(y => y.PartIsDeleted) == false

Comment: Difference - first "at least one False", second "not a single True".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 easy combinations in using `Any` and `All`.

1. Any
2. All
3. None

Be crystal clear which you do want.

---

At least one of `ListofParts` is not deleted.

```
ListOfCars.Where(x => x.ListofParts.Any(y => y.PartIsDeleted == false));
```

All of `ListofParts` are not deleted

```
ListOfCars.Where(x => x.ListofParts.All(y => y.PartIsDeleted == false));
```

None of `ListofParts` is deleted

```
ListOfCars.Where(x => x.ListofParts.Any(y => y.PartIsDeleted) == false);
```

Comment: I think you are right even your code is same as poster and he says it has problem

Comment: Hi Tommy, the third one did work! but may I ask a favor and can you explain why, I don't seem to see the difference between Any(y => y.PartIsDeleted == false) and Any(y => y.PartIsDeleted) == false

Comment: It is just logic. Try to say it in English and you will see the difference. https://dotnetfiddle.net/tw1Vcn

Comment: Look carefully at the close parentheses on the last one.